# Is it possible to sort a NSArray collection of UIView's based on their tag?

Tags: iphone, sorting, uiview, nsarray, tags

I've seen examples of something like

```
[someArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

I'm looking for an example that stores a collection of UIViews and I'd like to sort them in ascending or descending order based on tags I assume programatically when a new UIView is created.

If someone could provide a code example or instructions that would be fantastic

Answer (score 13, accepted):

NSArray provides a number of methods to sort an array (all listed under the "Sorting" header in the NSArray docs). You can define a function, a method or a sort descriptor to compare the views based on their tags for sorting. For example, here's an implementation using NSSortDescriptor:

```
NSSortDescriptor *ascendingSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"tag" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *descendingSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"tag" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortedArray = [someArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:ascendingSort]];
```

Comment: Hi Chuck I'm wondering if you could further assist, I'm curious whether this sort will work with using a UIView's frame.origin.y property (or any property by that matter), I am struggling to understand the way sorting works in Objective-C, I'm sure I'll get there, just hoping to do so sooner rather then later!  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compareTags:(UIView *)view {
    if ([self tag] == [view tag]) return NSOrderedSame;
    if ([self tag] > [view tag]) return NSOrderedDescending;
    return NSOrderedAscending;
}
```

Assuming I got the ordering right, that is, and the methods for this use would have to be on UIView (easily done with a category).  There are several other ways of getting the same result, see the docs [Sorting Arrays](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/sortingFilteringArrays.html#//apple%5Fref/doc/uid/TP40005176).

Comment: Thanks for this, I've gone for the NSSortDescriptor solution but I appreciate sound reply!